# Unable to run my test suite in (Spanish, German or French)

Tags: testing, automation, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

I have a MacBook Pro(macOS Big Sur v 11.4). I am unable to run my test suite in different browser languages like (German, Spanish or French).

I use this command `testcafe 'firefox --lang=es'` and I have tried both firefox and chrome, I tried `--lang=fr` and `--lang=ger` but nothing works.

I tried with double quote `testcafe "chrome --lang=fr-Fr"` as well.

Everytime I run my test, it execute successfully with no error but always run in English browser language.

And one more thing above code works fine on windows machine.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that on macOS, this method doesn't work out of the box whether or not you use TestCafe.

If you launch chrome with the `--lang=fr-FR` flag from the console directly (without TestCafe), it will not give the desired result.

Please see the following article and let us know if it helps: https://gist.github.com/kentbrew/e9449acd12c1ef2d78b5b473f615d23b.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention, I need to run TestCafe Automation suite which has about 200 tests, and it should automatically pick the language based on command like this `testcafe 'firefox --lang=es'`

Comment: Above, I provided a link to an article that illustrates how to configure Chrome on macOS, which will help you run Chrome with the required option.

As for Firefox, it doesn't seem to allow changing localization with `--lang` at all. In order to achieve your goal, you will need to use profiles. Check how to do this here: [https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/profile-manager-create-remove-switch-firefox-profiles](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/profile-manager-create-remove-switch-firefox-profiles).